# whats wrong with this in python 3.10.2

Tags: python, string

```
a=int("123.5")
print (a)
```

But WHY??
ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/pc/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/v.py", line 5, in <module>
    a=int("123.5")
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '123.5'
```

Comment: use a=float("123.5")

Comment: 123.5 cannot be an integer.

Comment: The OP is quite right: the behaviour of `int` must have changed, as in python 3.9.5, `help(int)` states `For floating point numbers, this truncates towards zero.`

Comment: @Pynchia A string containing a decimal number is not a floating point number.

Comment: @deceze yes, sorry. The problem lies in the type of the parameter, it's a string. BTW, try `>>> int(123.5)`

Comment: @Pynchia Yes, exactly. Nothing changed in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

An `int` is an integer number, like 1, 2, 3, etc. Python won't drop the decimal place (truncate) the number on a string-to-integer conversion like that. You'll need something like `int(float("123.5"))`. That converts the string to a float, and python *will* drop the fractional part from a `float` when converting to `int`.